# Keras Input arrays (x) can not have different number of samples?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I found in the current keras, All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples.

For many multi-input and multi-output models, it is more desirable if we can define different number of samples (aka. batch-size) for each inputs.

This is really important for the case one input X1 is much 'cheaper' than another input X2.

Say now I have two inputs X1, X2 and two outputs Y1, Y2. 
Y1 is a function of X1 and Y2 is a function of X1,X2.
The mapping X1->Y1 is much faster ('cheaper') to train than the mapping X1,X2->Y2.
So I may desire a large batch size of X1 and a small batch size of X2.

Or is it possible to hack the current code so as to make input with different batch-size possible?

Looking forward to anyone who can give me some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do different weights for your samples. By setting the sample weights variable (https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) your training algorithm will take cheaper samples into account.

If you want to train on different batch sizes you will need to use model.train_on_batch and pass in different batch sizes. This in essence means that you write your own fit loop.

Comment: `train_on_batch` should work. bucket training data by batch and train on the various buckets.

Comment: Hi Thomas and putonspectacles, thanks for your reply.


But my question is I want inputs [X1, X2] with different batch size. For example, X1 is with batch size 64 and X2 with batch size 256, that is the first dimension of input tensor of X1 and X2 are 64 and 256.


I've tried both fit_generator and train_on_batch, when I input X=[X1,X2], it throws the error:


 "ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(64, 200, 111), (64, 200), (64, 200), (256, 1), (256, 1)]"


I am not sure how sample weights would help here?

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried padding with dummy data the smaller input and then slicing it inside the network to discard it, however Keras won't allow that either because you can't use intermediate data as input. Were you able to solve the issue, jmore?

Comment: I have the same prole. Any solutions so far?

Comment: In tensorflow I would apply the network to both input tensors and then reduce the output to a single value via reduce_mean and then add them together and learn them jointly. I am not sure if this is possible in pure keras, but you can use tensorflow code in keras.